# Change the way how Netbeans auto formats for space indent for javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, netbeans, editor, autoformatting

Let's say we have the simple code as below.

```
console.log(''+'Abb'+' '+'122');
```

And we want to make the argument clearer. We then change it to `wanted form` like below

```
console.log(''
    + 'Abb' 
    + ' ' 
    + '122'
);
```

Now comes the issue when we call Netbeans to format our code via Alt-Shift-F (menu: Source - Format)

The code turned into the form as below

```
console.log(''
    + 'Abb'
    + ' '
    + '122'
    );
```

How can we change this to 1) the spaces and 2) the close parenthese ) position as in the `wanted form` above?

Answer (score 2):

Go to

```
Tools > Options > Editor Tab > Formatting Tab > Select Language > Select Category
```

Now you have all the options of indentation that you can explore by yourself according to your needs.

Comment: I can just find the spaces configuration there. None for the parenthese position.

Comment: You might want to adjust the "initial indentation" and "continuation indentation" settings (language-specific). Changing those solved a problem I had with the lines inside the function ("continuation lines") having too much leading indentation.